# How to get parameter values in string.xml from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my MainActivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String myString = "Mary";
        int myInt = 12;
        String formatted = getString(R.string.my_xml_string, myString, myInt);

    }
}
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="my_xml_string">My sister %1$s is %2$d years old.</string>
</resources>
```

However when I run the app,I still got 'My sister %1$s is %2$d years old.' as text. Anyone knows why?

On the side note, it says the variable formatted is not used. So how does that link to the string.xml file?

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHqOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, I use

```
#setText to pass value
RandomGeneratedNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.random);
RandomGeneratedNumber.setText(random_generated_number);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String mString = getString(R.string.hello);
```

or

```
String mString= getResources().getString(R.string.hello);
```